# How do I get all assets in a given UserAssetLibrary with the Python API?

Tags: python, asset, asset-browser

Part of my addon's functionality is to replace local materials with their counterparts in linked libraries / assets.

In order to check if a material of the same name as a local material is available as an asset in the asset browser, I need some way to iterate through all assets of a given UserAssetLibrary and check for matches.

Unfortunately, I've not been able to find a method to get all assets contained in a UserAssetLibrary so far. After browsing the Data API it also doesn't seem like those are stored anywhere in the current BLEND file in the first place.

I suspect that since the asset browser seems to be a version of the file browser, I need to instead look into methods of getting a list of all files listed in the file browser. What I've found there has mostly been about finding the selcted file(s) though, not *all* files.

see:

- [bpy/file browser: get selected file names](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30678/bpy-file-browser-get-selected-file-names)
- [How to access all selected files from a file selector in Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45646/how-to-access-all-selected-files-from-a-file-selector-in-python)

Part of the function where this would be used below. Currently it only checks for linked files, but assets in the browser do not show up as materials in `bpy.data.materials`, and as such I cannot check for matches.

```
        for slot in obj.material_slots:
            if slot.material is not None and slot.material.library is None:
                old_material = slot.material
                new_material = None
                
                for mtl in bpy.data.materials:
                    # If an object is imported that has a material that already exists in the scene, it is numbered.
                    # Thus checking the substring of the name is necessary to catch all of them.
                    if mtl.library != None and ( mtl.name == old_material.name or mtl.name == old_material.name[:-4] ) and old_material.seut.overrideMatLib == False:
                        new_material = mtl
                        break                            

                if new_material != None:
                    slot.material = new_material
                    if old_material not in mtl_to_delete:
                        mtl_to_delete.append(old_material)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [asset libraries](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PreferencesFilePaths.html#bpy.types.PreferencesFilePaths.asset_libraries) are stored in the preferences [filepaths](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Preferences.html#bpy.types.Preferences.filepaths). [Preferences](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Preferences.html#preferences-bpy-struct) are accessed with the [current context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.preferences).

An [User Asset Library](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UserAssetLibrary.html#bpy.types.UserAssetLibrary) object holds the name of the library and the path to its root directory.

You can load the contents with [bpy.data.libraries.load](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.load) and the argument `assets_only=True` to filter only assets. Thanks to [viktor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265798/86891) for pointing it out.

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

prefs = bpy.context.preferences
filepaths = prefs.filepaths
asset_libraries = filepaths.asset_libraries

for asset_library in asset_libraries:
    library_name = asset_library.name
    library_path = Path(asset_library.path)
    blend_files = [fp for fp in library_path.glob("**/*.blend") if fp.is_file()]
    print(f"Checking the content of library '{library_name}' :")
    for blend_file in blend_files:
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(str(blend_file), assets_only=True) as (file_contents, _):
            # Note this will print out the names of the objects,
            # Not the actual objects
            print(file_contents.objects)
            print(file_contents.materials)
            print(file_contents.worlds)
            # etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are loading a library with `bpy.data.libraries.load(str(blend_file))`, you can use `assets_only=True` keyword in order to load only assets instead of all contents.

Comment: Ooh nice find, thanks for sharing ! I modified my answer to take it into account. Cheers